# Microsoft Word - Using Regex to delete everything after characters

Tags: regex, ms-word

I have a lot of html that has table id numbers and want to have a regex that finds the line of code that contains the id # and then lets me delete everything after that.

What I currently have:

```
<table id="tableid-140" border="80">
```

What I want:

```
<table>
```

Update: I have found a way to Find every line that has table in it and delete it.  Now I need help to Replace the line with `<table>`

```
    Sub TestMacroI()
Dim oRng As Word.Range
Dim oRngDelete As Word.Range
Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range
With oRng.Find
  .Text = "table"
  While .Execute
    oRng.Select
    Set oRngDelete = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\Line").Range
    oRngDelete.Delete
  Wend
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a *wildcard* Find/Replace, where:

```
Find = (\<table) id*^13
Replace = \1>^p
```

No code required - though it could be encoded in a macro.

Comment: I wish I could upvote but I don't have enough reputation.  Thank you very much for the help.